# Hibernate search creating unnecessary threads to index data on server startup.With default "hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners" configuration

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

We have upgraded our system hibernate to 5.4.12 and hibernate search orm to 5.11.5. Websphere 8.5.5.16.

As I saw on the official hibernate documentation the below line:

> The good news is that Hibernate Search is enabled out of the box when
>   detected on the classpath by Hibernate ORM. If for some reason you
>   need to disable it set hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners to
>   false. **Note that there is no performance penalty when the listeners
>   are enabled but no entities are annotated as indexed**.

I would like to bring your attention to the bold text above. Even though the documentation says it will not give us any performance issue and entities will not be indexed. 
This is not working as designed. On server start up we are seeing multiple threads being executed to index the entities marked with @Indexed annotation. And due to which the server sometimes throws out of memory exception for heap.

This does not happens if I go with overriding the default config as below:

```
<property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
```

But again I face an issue, which I've reported below.

**Hibernate config file**

```
 <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager">elasticsearch</property>
 <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host">http://ip:9400</property>
 <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy">none</property>
 <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status">yellow</property>
 <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.infostream">true</property>
```

Above is the issue with new upgrade.

I do have one more issue, what if I setup my hibernate config file with below

```
<property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
```

I do not face the above mentioned issue any longer, but again I am not able to recreate my indexes(by using *hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy=drop-and-create*) with this configuration as "false".
To overcome this I'll first have to set "*hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners*" to true and then start my server again, but I may again face the thread/out of memory issue.

Also, while creating the initial indexes, I thought to override the hibernate config property(with *org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration* class) "*hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners*" to true, and it may work at that point in time(did not try though). 
I'm curious to understand the new configuration(hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners=true) and why its not working as designed or is it working as designed. Because this unnecessary(please pardon this word if not appropriate) threads are killing my application performance.

Is this hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners default enabled functionality working as designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, this was not an issue with Hibernate Search and was related to some other part of my application, which was creating the out of memory issues. This we found out after disabling the Hibernate Search and analyzing the thread dumps, as we were facing issue of Out of Memory even without Hibernate Search.

Plus, we did increase/then decreased the memory allocation for our application in order to perform an iterative analysis of the application performance.

Will also put the same information on Hibernate forum.

Answer (score 0):

`hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` controls whether Hibernate Search is enabled. That's confusing, I know, but it's a legacy setting. It will be renamed to just `hibernate.search.enabled` in Hibernate Search 6.

> > Note that there is no performance penalty when the listeners are enabled but no entities are annotated as indexed.
>
> I would like to bring your attention to the bold text above. Even though the documentation says it will not give us any performance issue and entities will not be indexed. This is not working as designed. On server start up we are seeing multiple threads being executed to index the entities marked with @Indexed annotation. And due to which the server sometimes throws out of memory exception for heap.

The documentation states that **if no entities are annotated as indexed**, there is no performance penalty to leaving this setting to the default (`true`). You said there are entities marked with `@Indexed`. Therefore there is a performance penalty.

Regardless... I'd stay away from this setting. It probably doesn't do what you think it does.

If you want to enable Hibernate Search, but prevent automatic indexing, see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_automatic_indexing) instead. You just have to set this:

```
hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual
```

Hibernate Search will still start up, but entity persisting events will be ignored. You will have to use the mass indexer in order to index your data, or explicit `index` commands. See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex) for more information.

**EDIT:** To answer your (many) comments.

> but am curious why did we introduce this setting? As this was working as expected under the older version of hibernate.

I'll need to know which setting you're talking about. Both `autoregister_listeners` and `indexing_strategy` were introduced before version `5.6`, so long before Elasticsearch support was event introduced.

> My concern is, we do have an option of create-and-drop of indexes at sever startup, are we going to remove this option?

No.

> If not, we can not leverage its benefits with current scenario.

You cannot leverage Hibernate Search if your disable Hibernate Search. That's true.

> Also, by mass indexer do you mean using the JSR-352 mass indexing job? or we are talking about .startAndWait process

`MassIndexer.startAndWait` is easier to get working. JSR-352 may not work in Websphere, I've never tried it.

> if yes does it drops and recreates the indexes

No. It just removes all documents, but it preserves the same schema.

The option to drop and recreate indexes in the mass indexer was introduced in Search 6.0.0.Beta6 ([HSEARCH-3751](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3751)); see the `dropAndCreateSchemaOnStart` parameter [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-massindexer-parameters).

> "Hibernate Search will still start up, but entity persisting events will be ignored. " will keeping this setting to false also stop automatic update on elastic side post hibernate operations of save/update/delete

Yes that is the point.

> If yes then the whole purpose of using hibernate search ORM is gone

No, that's useful to trigger mass indexing, reindex your data while taking your application offline. After that, you can restart your application and re-enable automatic indexing.

Some people also don't use automatic indexing at all and just reindex their whole database periodically. That's not for everyone, though.

> `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` settings as false then while executing fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait() am receiving org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized

As I already explained, setting `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` to `false` will just **disable Hibernate Search**. So yes, that's expected.

> Why do I suspect the whole meaning of hibernate search ORM usage under a hibernate project is lost with this new version

I honestly don't know. The settings you're mentioning did not change for ages.

> I can not use the hibernate search at all and if its true than I've the performance issue at startup

**That**'s what you should focus on.

Where do the problems seem to happen? Just when booting? Or when the application handles HTTP requests that result in write operations on the database?

Did you change anything at all?

- Changes in your model and Search mapping could lead to dramatic performance problems if they trigger a lot of reindexing (`@ContainedIn`). I'm talking about indexing *one* entity leading to loading half the database. You need to be very careful about what you do with `@ContainedIn`.
- Switching from Lucene to Elasticsearch can also represent a high cost if your application is very write-intensive. In particular, you should not enable `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.refresh_after_write`. This setting will lead to terrible performance in write-intensive applications.

> As due to this flag(hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners) being false this drop-and-create functionality does not have a significance any more

As I explained above, with `autoregister_listeners` set to `false`, Hibernate Search is disabled. So of course all Hibernate Search features are disabled as well.

Comment: Thanks @yrodiere for the inputs, but am curious why did we introduce this setting? As this was working as expected under the older version of hibernate. My concern is, we do have an option of create-and-drop of indexes at sever startup, are we going to remove this option? If not, we can not leverage its benefits with current scenario.
Also, by mass indexer do you mean using the JSR-352 mass indexing job? or we are talking about .startAndWait process, if yes does it drops and recreates the indexes?
Using index command will not solve my purpose though.

Comment: another question with respect to "Hibernate Search will still start up, but entity persisting events will be ignored. " will keeping this setting  to false also stop automatic update on elastic side post hibernate operations of save/update/delete. If yes then the whole purpose of using hibernate search ORM is gone.
Please share your thought around this.
And are we planning to overcome all these in version 6.

Comment: One more thing from my side. If I have `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` settings as false then while executing `fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait()` am receiving `org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized`.

**Why do I suspect the whole meaning of hibernate search ORM usage under a hibernate project is lost with this new version. If `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` is false I can not use the hibernate search at all and if its true than I've the performance issue at startup. :(**

Comment: could you please share the thoughts from Hibernate team on the questions I've put above. 
Is this a bug in 5.4.12? As due to this flag(`hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners`) being false this drop-and-create functionality does not have a significance any more.

Comment: I edited my answer to address your comments. 
If you need to ask any more questions, please ask on [our forums](https://discourse.hibernate.org/c/hibernate-search/6). Stackoverflow is definitely not adapted to such back-and-forth conversations.

Comment: point noted. I've replied on the same [thread](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3900) created on your forum.